# Ghc not starting properly [Windows 7 64 bit]

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've just installed Haskell Platform, and ghci works fine, but for some reason i can't launch ghc. It crashes approximately 0,5 seconds after i start it.

In the haskell platform directory, i've got the following "ghc-related" .exe's:
ghc
ghc.pkg
runghc

runghc.exe "works", but the only thing that happens is that a blank, black terminal appears.

Help!

Comment: "Launching ghc" doesn't do anything by itself. You need to run it from a terminal and add the filename you want to compile.

Comment: So when i start runghc.exe, it's supposed to just launch a blank terminal? I've only used Haskell on linux previosly, where you first load into ghc, and then you type "ghci" to run ghci. But i don't have a ghc-terminal, it's just ghci.

Comment: I don't know what Linux package you're talking about, but if I want ghci on my Linux system, I only need to type `ghci` in a console. So what exactly do you mean by "I can't launch ghc" if ghci works fine for you?

Comment: I am using the haskell platform for Windows. There are lots of .exe's in the folder haskellplatform. Ghci is it's own .exe, you don't go through ghc to launch it. Ghc is also a .exe, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well how do you launch it and what does "it doesn't work for me" mean? Double-clicking ghc.exe isn't *meant* to do anything by itself!

Comment: @user2851582 Try dragging and dropping a Haskell source file over the `ghc.exe` executable instead. That should compile your Haskell code to a runnable program file!

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from your comments, I'd say you don't quite understand what GHC is and what GHCi is.  GHC is the Glasgow Haskell Compiler.  All it does is compile your Haskell code into an executable.  GHCi is the interactive GHC, it lets you type in code and have it compiled line-by-line.  You can launch GHCi by running `ghci` from your command line, but when you run `ghc`, you have to pass it more arguments to have it do anything.

For example, if I had the file `HelloWorld.hs` in the folder `C:\projects\haskell`, with `HelloWorld.hs` having the contents

```hs
module Main where

sayHello :: String -> String
sayHello name = "Hello, " ++ name ++ "!"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "What is your name?"
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn $ sayHello name
```

I could open a command line (the `>` indicates the prompt, it isn't part of the commands) and run

```
> cd C:\projects\haskell
> ghc --make HelloWorld.hs -o hello.exe
> hello.exe
What is your name?
bheklilr
Hello, bheklilr!
```

I could also do something like

```
> cd C:\projects\haskell
> ghci
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :load HelloWorld.hs
Ok, modules loaded: Main
*Main>
```

From which point I can do things like

```
*Main> sayHello "World"
"Hello, World!"
*Main> sayHello $ sayHello "World"
"Hello, Hello, World!!"
*Main> :main
What is your name?
bheklilr
Hello, bheklilr!
```